# Elasticsearch jdbc-importer in Nodejs and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, jdbc

I want to use Elasticsearch within my project. I am using Nodejs and postgresql.

I want to connect postgresql with elasticsearch for this i am using  [jdbc-importer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc). I followed the steps written in their docs to connect with postgresql and i succeded in this but through command line.

I want to use jdbc-importer within my project through nodejs

commondline code to run jdbc importer:

```
bin=/Users/mac/Documents/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1/bin
lib=/Users/mac/Documents/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1/lib
echo '{
     "type" : "jdbc",
     "jdbc" : {
         "url" : 
        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/development",
        "sql" : "select * from \"Products\"",
         "index" : "product",
         "type" : "product",
    "elasticsearch" : {
    "cluster" : "elasticsearch",
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : 9300
}
     }
 }' | java \
        -cp "${lib}/*" \
        org.xbib.tools.Runner \
        org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```

above command have created index product in elasticsearch and it also have data from Products table of postgresql.

Now, I want to use that jdbc importer through nodejs and If anyone elso knows other efficient way to manage my postgresql data in elasticsearch they are also welcome to give answere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logstash:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

With it you can transfer data from Postgres into ElasticSearch. This is my config file:

```
input { 
  jdbc {
    # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDB"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => ""
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-42.1.1.jar"
    # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * from contacts"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "contacts"
    document_type => "contact"
    document_id => "%{uid}"
  }
}
```